# redux-form validate not getting any values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a React Component, QuizContainer, connected to Redux for some other state data.

This component has a  component inside it called "title".
I'm trying to get the validation function to run for my fields, but it only seem to output an empty object, and only when registering the  component.

Is there something wrong with this?

**UPDATE: Full component**

```
class QuizContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contentpanel">
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                        <Field name="title" component={titleField} type="text" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        quiz: state.quiz,
        mediaPanel: state.mediaPanel
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(quizActions, dispatch)
    }
}

const titleField = ({input,
    value,
    label,
    type,
    meta: { touched, error, warning }}) => (
    <div>
        <input {...input} type={type} value={value}/>
        {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
)

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    if(values.title && values.title.length < 10){
        errors.title = 'Title is missing';
    }
    return errors;
}

QuizContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuizContainer);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'quiz',
    validate
})(QuizContainer)
```

Comment: can you post the whole your component?

Comment: @seethrough yes, see update